# Apparent anomaly in coefficients in multinomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

I am seeing some results that point to a clear conceptual gap in my understanding of multinomial logistic regression and am seeking an explanation.

I am performing multinomial logistic regression on a dataset in which the dependent variable has three levels. I first cross-tabulated the relationship between the dependent variable y (with levels y1, y2 and y3) and one categorical independent variable x (with levels x1 and x2). The cross-table of x and y showing row-wise percentages looks like this:

```
                  y
         --------------------
         |   y1    y2    y3
  |--------------------------
  |  x1  |  47.6   28.4. 23.9
x |  x2  |  26.1   21.4. 52.5
```

From the above table, it is clear that the probability of y3 is much higher when x = x2 than when x = x1. Also, the odds of y3 relative to y1 are also much higher when x = x2 than when x = x1.

I then ran a multinomial logistic regression with **several independent variables in addition to x**, with y = y1 and x = x1 as the reference values. I got the following coefficients for x from the regression:

```
====================================================
                  Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                    y2        y3        
----------------------------------------------------
x_x2              1.079***    -0.484***  
----------------------------------------------------
```

From the coefficients, I can see that the log odds of y3 relative to y1 will **decrease** by 0.484 when x changes from x1 to x2. This seems like an anomaly given how the odds of y3 relative to y1 in the cross-table above are much higher for x = x2 than for x = x1. Of course, I understand that in the regression, I am using many other independent variables and that these could have an impact, but am unable to see how such an impact might come about.

I would appreciate if someone can throw more light on how the presence of other independent variables can cause something like this to happen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not (yet) appear to be a computer programming question. This appears to be a math/statistics question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have now posted this question in Crossvalidated. I posted here because I have received responses to such questions earlier in this forum.